# Copy contents of element to clipboard with zClip via data-attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, zclip

I've gotten the [zClip plugin](http://www.steamdev.com/zclip/) to work like this:

```
<p class="thing">Click the link below to copy this text...</p>
<a class="copy" href="">copy</a>


$('a.copy').zclip({
    path:'lib/js/ZeroClipboard.swf',
    copy:$('.thing').text()
});
```

But I would like to have many copy links on a page that each copy a different element by way of data-attribute:

```
<p class="thing">Click the link below to copy this text...</p>
<a class="copy" data-copy=".thing" href="">copy</a>

$('.copy').zclip({
    path:'lib/js/ZeroClipboard.swf',
    copy:function(){return $(this).data('copy').val();}
});
```

The above is me taking a stab in the dark at it but it obviously doesn't work.

Any idea how to accomplish this? I'm also not opposed to using a different plugin as long as it's rather simple to implement.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: if `$('.copy')` is returning a value you may need to wrap a .each around the zclip function. some plugins can't handle multiple selectors. so it would be something like $('a.copy').each(function(){ $(this).zclip({path:'lib/js/ZeroClipboard.swf',copy:$('.thing').text)});

Comment: @Shanimal I think the problem is my use of `$(this)`, but I don't know how to solve that since I need to make each `.copy` work relative to itself

Comment: $(this) is scoped to the current element in the `.each` iteration

Comment: @Shanimal I think the .zclip function isn't aware of `$(this)` inside the `copy:` variable for some reason

Comment: zclip in the jsbin link doesn't work because the path to zclip swf isn't available, but the idea was to describe how to use `each` to hit each instance separately. hope its helpful.  
http://jsbin.com/hasicemi/1/edit